# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.getpostman.com

Tags: postman, newman

For several days I'm seeing intermittent error while making call to Postman API to fetch  collections or Environment. However, most often, if you run it again, it works fine.

The code is straightforward (using Node):

**collections**

```
const response = await axios.get(`https://api.getpostman.com/collections/${collectionId}?apikey=${key}`)
```

**Error (failing to load collection intermittently)**

```
Error: collection could not be loaded unable to fetch data from url "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/<id>?apikey=<key>" 
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.getpostman.com
```

---

**environment**

```
const response = await axios.get(`https://api.getpostman.com/environments/${environmentId}?apikey=${apiKey}`)
```

**Error (failing to load Environment intermittently):**

```
run-try-err Error: could not load environment
  Something went wrong with the server.
    at done (/Users/deepakaggarwal/Documents/Projects/newman-runner/node_modules/newman/lib/run/options.js:119:40)
    at /Users/deepakaggarwal/Documents/Projects/newman-runner/node_modules/newman/lib/run/options.js:79:24
   ...
```

What could be the reason of this intermittent issue? Is there a problem with Postman APIs?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. We are using newman and get intermittent errors like "error: could not load environment. Something went wrong with the server". 

We also get (which would indicate Postman returned some kind of html page)
 `error: could not load environment
  Unexpected token '<' at 1:1
<html>
^